# begin postgresql 9.2 default timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

everybody

I found begin postgresql 9.2；when installed postgresql，the postgresql timezone is GMT;before
9.2 ,like 9.1.6,the postgresql timiezone is set by system timezone

for example

9.1.6

```
postgres(at)postgres 2014-01-23_16:34:30 ([local]:5432)  # select now();
+-------------------------------+
|              now              |
+-------------------------------+
| 2014-01-23 16:34:33.817441+08 |
+-------------------------------+
(1 row)

Time: 13.034 ms

| TimeZone                        | PRC
```

9.2.4

```
postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2014-01-23 08:35:27.509442+00
(1 row)

 TimeZone                        | GMT
```

so, after postgresql 9.1 , like 9.2  should setting postgresql timezone in  postgresql data directory  postgresql.conf??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 9.2, postgresql would probe the system timezone at startup. This was apparently an expensive check, so note it is probed when initdb is performed, and an initial value set in postgresql.conf. if you remove the setting from postgresql.conf it will go with a default of GMT.

If your server is defaulting to GMT then either the probing process did not work when you upgraded, or perhaps you accidentally overwrote the value in the conf file.

See: [Timezone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) and [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-2.html) (search for timezone).